# Why does datetime__range work incorrectly?

Tags: django, datetime, django-views

**views**

```
import datetime
from .models import AccountTransaction


date = datetime.datetime.today()

def account_transactions_week_view(request):
    account_transactions = AccountTransaction.objects.filter(user_id = request.user.id).filter(datetime__range=[date - datetime.timedelta(days=7), date])
```

**models**

```
class AccountTransaction(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name=_('user'))
    datetime = models.DateTimeField(_('created at'), auto_now_add=True)
```

I bring to the page a list of recent entries over the past week. For this I use a filter.

I wondered why this variant does not work correctly (new entries appear after a while):

```
filter(datetime__range=[date - datetime.timedelta(days=7), date])
```

But this variant works correctly:

```
filter(datetime__gt=date - datetime.timedelta(days=7))
```

*I wonder what's wrong with the first one?*

There are **middleware**

```
class TimezoneMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request):
        tzname = request.session.get('django_timezone')
        if not tzname:
            request.session['django_timezone'] = 'Europe/Kiev'
            tzname = 'Europe/Kiev'
        timezone.activate(pytz.timezone(tzname))
```

**settings**

```
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
```

Comment: I'm not too sure about it but in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#range) it's said you should pass a `start_date` and an `end_date` and you're wrapping those into a []. Perhaps try to define `start_date` and `end_date` before and then using the `range` lookup.

Comment: What is wrong when you use `range`? WHat new entries appear? Could you explain a bit?

Comment: `new entries appear after a while` means, they start appearing the next day? datetime != date. {today} + any non zero time > {date:today}. Try `datetime__date__range` or change date to {today+1}

Comment: @SergeyPugach When I use a `range`, new entries (which have been added to the database) are not immediately displayed on the user’s page, but after a while. When using `gt`, everything works correctly.

Comment: @IvanStarostin `new entries appear after a while` means, they start appearing after few minutes or hours (at the users page)

Comment: Please show the whole context of those queries. Are they at class level? Exactly where is `date` defined?

Comment: Please provide minimal repro or sample data and the resultset you receive when using __range.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Added view and model

Comment: @IvanStarostin thnx. `datetime__date__range` - it's work. But I still do not understand what the difference is between the `datetime__range` and the `datetime__date__range`. That was the purpose of my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've defined `date` outside the method. That means the definition is executed when the module is first imported, when the Django process starts up. It will keep the same value for all uses of that process, until the server decides to recycle  it and create a new one. So your range query will use the original value as the end point for all queries during the lifetime of the process.

The solution is to simply move the definition to inside the view function.

(Your other query works because it is simply doing "everything greater than 7 days since the original date", which automatically includes things greater than the original date.)

Comment: Which method is better?